# write a program that calculates the number of comparisons in binary insertion sorting?

Tags: sorting, binary, insertion

I would like to know how I can write a program to calculate the number of comparison in binary insertion sorting

I tried to code the binary insertion program below, but I would like to know how I can calculate the overall comparisons made.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int binarysearch (int a[], int sel, int high, int low){
int mid=(high+low)/2;
if(high<=low){
if(sel>a[high]){
return high+1;
}
else{
    return high;
}
}
else{
if(sel==a[mid]){
return mid+1;
}
else if(sel>a[mid]){
return binarysearch( a,  sel,  high,  mid+1);
}
else{
return binarysearch( a,  sel,  mid-1,  low);
}
}}
void insertionsort(int a[], int n){
for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
int j=i-1;
int sel=a[i];
int loc=binarysearch(a,sel,j,0);
while(j>=loc){
a[j+1]=a[j];
j--;
}
a[j+1]=sel;
}
}
int main(){
int a[]= {1,6,2,5,3,4};
int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
insertionsort(a,n);
 cout<<"Sorted array is :";
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a counter and increment it every time you perform a comparison?

Comment: do i add the counter after every if/else statement